# How to check for each row of a table, the value of the selected select instead of getting all the available options and text input values

Tags: javascript, jquery

[JSFidle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/cLxzfury/62/)

I have implemented the following jQuery function:

```
$( "#btn-ts-today-save" ).click(function() {
  $("#tm-todays-entries-table tr").each(function () {
    var self = $(this);    
    var col_1_value = self.find("td:eq(0)").text().trim(); //I want the selected value, not all the values
    var col_2_value = self.find("td:eq(1)").text().trim(); //I want the selected value, not all the values
    var col_3_value = self.find("td:eq(2)").text().trim();
    var col_4_value = self.find("td:eq(3)").text().trim(); //I want the selected value, not all the values
    var col_5_value = self.find("td:eq(4)").text().trim();
    var col_6_value = self.find("td:eq(5)").text().trim(); //I want the selected value, not all the values
    var col_7_value = self.find("td:eq(6)").text().trim(); //I want the selected value, not all the values
    var col_8_value = self.find("td:eq(7)").text().trim(); //I want the selected value, not all the values
    var result = col_1_value + " - " + col_2_value + " - " + col_3_value + " - " + col_4_value + col_5_value + " - " + col_6_value + " - " + col_7_value + " - " + col_8_value;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
});
```

Basically what I do is loop through the entire table and print the contents of each cell,
but that is not what I want as now I am returning all the options for each select and I just want to know the 'selected' option -not all-. Also I want to get the value that the user has introduced in the input text box, but it does not work.

Can someone help me find the best solution?

Comment: Sounds like you just need `self.find('td select')` and then possibly `map()` to build an array of the values. It would help a lot to see the associated HTML and a working example of the issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for your reply, I added a JSFiddle.

Comment: `var col_1_value = self.find("td:eq(0) select").text().trim(); `

It doesn't work with select...

Comment: Also please note that after looking at your html, you are duplication lots of ID's. An ID should always be unique.

Comment: I just quickly copied and pasted the code and hardcoded certain parts, I missed it. sorry for the id duplicates.

Comment: @Cheknov have you tested my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have done some mistakes on your code: (trap a data from an input text is not the same method than from an option)

```
 $( "#btn-ts-today-save" ).click(function() {
    $("#tm-todays-entries-table tbody tr").each(function () {
        var self = $(this);    
        var col_1_value = self.find("td:eq(0) select option:selected").text().trim(); 
        var col_2_value = self.find("td:eq(1) select option:selected").text().trim(); 
        var col_3_value = self.find("td:eq(2) input[type='text']").val().trim(); 
        var col_4_value = self.find("td:eq(3) select option:selected").text().trim(); 
        var col_5_value = self.find("td:eq(4) input[type='text']").val().trim();
        var col_6_value = self.find("td:eq(5) select option:selected").text().trim(); 
        var col_7_value = self.find("td:eq(6) select option:selected").text().trim(); 
        var col_8_value = self.find("td:eq(7) select option:selected").text().trim(); 
        var result = col_1_value + " - " + col_2_value + " - " + col_3_value + " - " + col_4_value + col_5_value + " - " + col_6_value + " - " + col_7_value + " - " + col_8_value;
        console.log(result);
    });
  });
```

if you want to simplify the code and avoid to use a number for col:

```
  var result=[];
  $( "#btn-ts-today-save" ).click(function() {
    $("#tm-todays-entries-table tbody tr").each(function () {
       var options = $(this).find("select option:selected").map( (_, e) => $(e).text().trim() ).get();
       var msgs = $(this).find("input[type='text']").map( (_, e) => $(e).val().trim() ).get();
       options.splice(2, 0, msgs[0]);
       options.splice(4, 0, msgs[1]);
       result.push(options);
       console.log(options);
    });
     console.log(result);
  })
```